# How do I remove another computer which has remote access to my laptop?

Tags: command-line, networking, remote-access

I visited a friend recently and he uploaded Linux on my laptop. He uploaded many programs from his laptop unto mine using a terminal. To do this he had to add a very long code from his laptop onto my laptop using my terminal and visa versa from mine to his using his terminal to give him remote access through his wifi to my laptop. I am new to the Linux OS and still have much to learn so please bear with my ignorance.

My question: How do I find that long code and remove it and what would be the right terminology to describe what he did on my laptop? Did he merely create a network group through terminal or did he open a kind of a door which only he knows of?

```
$ dpkg -s openssh-server | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `dpkg -s openssh-server | grep Status` to your question. This checks whether this package is installed on your system, ssh is *the* way to set up a connection like you describe. If it is installed and you don’t want it to be, simply remove it with `sudo apt remove openssh-server` and restart.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to allow remote access to your computer, ranging from standard solutions (like ssh) to secret backdoors. Do you fully trust your friend? If so, ask them to describe what they did and to undo it, they know it much better than any of us could figure out. If not, reinstall your system from scratch, without their help.

Comment: By the looks of it I am almost certain that it is an openssh-server. I checked and openssh-server is installed. How can I check for the accounts that has access to it? The article at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring helped allot, but I cant seem to find a way to check for accounts.

Comment: I don`t want to assume that the openssh-server is in fact the way he gained access to my laptop. I would like to verify it. Also as I am still learning to code and have little to no knowledge of ssh, I think it would make a good exercise to manually remove his account.

Comment: Regarding my main question I am sure by removing the openssh-server will resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Another option would be to ask your friend what he did to your laptop. Our knowledge is naturally limited.

Answer (score 1):

With `dpkg -s openssh-server | grep Status` returning `installed` you have confirmed that someone installed an SSH server on your machine, as this package is **not installed by default** in any of the current Ubuntu releases ([see their `.manifest` files](https://askubuntu.com/a/48894/507051)). If you don’t need remote access to your machine and want to make sure nobody else is using `ssh` to get access either, simply remove this package with

```
sudo apt remove openssh-server
```

and either reboot or stop the `sshd` service with

```
systemctl stop sshd
```

and kill any connection that may still be active with:

```
killall sshd
```

Manually removing an SSH user is more complicated and requires much more information than you gave us, but these questions might be helpful:

- [How to log off an user from SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36113/507051)
- [What is a user-friendly way to log off other users?](https://askubuntu.com/q/52971/507051)
- [How to delete useless ssh key on my server(Ubuntu server 16.04) and generate new one](https://askubuntu.com/q/916907/507051)